# Doubt on Fundamental Limit reduction

Tags: calculus, limits

I've recently learned about the fundamental limit and it's proof by the squeeze theorem, but now, I have the following task.

$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin{3x}}{x}$

I've looked at my old notes on trigonometrical identities, But I haven't managed to reduce this to a form of the $3$ multiplying $x$ goes out of the $\sin$ function.

Any tips ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happen if we set $$3x=y$$?

Comment: Then we have $\lim_x{\sin{y}}{x}$, but this squeeze theorem isn't only true when the sine argument is equals to function denominator ?

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin 3x}{x} =  \lim_{x \to 0} \frac 31\cdot \frac {\sin 3x}{3x} = 3\cdot 1 = 3$$

We're using the fact that $$\lim_{\alpha\to 0} \dfrac {\sin \alpha}{\alpha} = 1.$$ In this case, $\alpha = 3x$.

Note, alternatively, that the posted limit initially evaluates to an indeterminate form $\dfrac 00$. Using L'Hospital, we get $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin 3x}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{3\cos 3x}{1} = \frac {3\cdot 1}{1} = 3$$

Comment: This rule only states for what you shown with \alpha, the sine argument must be equals to it's denominator ? And how about when we can't separate the denominator in a multiplication which does not affect the result ? like sin(4x)/sin(3x).

Comment: Isn't it true that $$\dfrac{\sin(3x)}{x} = \frac{3}{3}\cdot \frac{\sin(3x)}{x} = \frac{3}1\cdot \frac{\sin(3x)}{(3x)}\quad?$$ I didn't do anything to the argument of $\sin$. What I did was multiply the given function by $\frac 33 = 1$, hence it doesn't change the function, it simply allows for a nice representation of the function.

Comment: You're welcome, aajjbb.

Answer (score 1):

Other two methods 
1st method:
$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{sin 3x}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{cos 3x}{1} \times 3$ [By L'Hospital's Rule]
$=3$.

2nd method:

for any $\epsilon >0$ $|\frac{sin 3x}{x} - 3|=|\frac{sin 3x - 3x}{x}|<\epsilon $ [As |sin x|<|x|] whenever $|x|<\delta$

So,$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{sin 3x}{x}=3$